# What is a synonym for "aftermath" but with a positive connotation?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'd like to use a synonym for "aftermath" without the negative connotation. My context is a wedding ceremony or party, and "everybody is still hyped up in its [aftermath]."

I can be flexible, so the answer doesn't have to fit exactly into the template "in its ____".

Comment: You limit your choices with the construction, "in its _____". Perhaps if you relax the construction, other ways of expressing the idea might come to mind. For example, you might consider  "in the excitement left over from the party".  You could look for a phrase to replace "left over".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, yes, I initially mentioned that I didn't mind flexibility, but I guess that part was edited out of the post, so... :/ Thanks for your idea! I'll look into "left over".

Comment: Do you specifically mean the celebration after the wedding ceremony ('reception') or the general period of say a few days or so after the wedding?

Comment: @DavidBodow, I mean the general period after both the ceremony and reception. It's a grand event, so the euphoria lingers on after the big day :)

Answer (score 1):

'Wake' works.  It's more neutral than positive, but the meaning should be clear.

*... everybody is still hyped up in its wake*.

Comment: However, 'wake' also often refers to a funeral or vigil after a death and could therefore have negative connotations.

Comment: True, but not quite.  Wake in that sense refers to the *party* after a death - celebrating the person's life - and is a helping mechanism to overcome the grief.  The association with death could be perceived negatively, but the effects of the wake itself are positive.

Comment: While some wakes may be positive celebrations of the deceased's life, overall, I see the main activity being mourning-centered / negative (via a sense of loss). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_(ceremony)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the word "aftereffect."

Also, "aftermath" does not necessarily have a bad connotation. I learned the word from a book in which the main character deals with the aftermath of escaping from some bandits and making off with their money.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prefix "post-_____" ;  which means after in time or sequence; following; subsequent.

post-wedding ceremony

Answer (score -1):

Backwash, wake, and consequence come to mind.

I think all three basically mean the same thing.  For instance:

> "In the **wake** of the scandal, the President resigned from office."
>
> "In the **aftermath** of the scandal, the President resigned from
>   office."
>
> "In the **backwash** of the scandal, the President resigned from
>   office."
>
> "As a **consequence** of the scandal, the President resigned from
>   office."

The word "aftereffect" could be used; however, it usually means that there was a delay involved in the response:

> "As an **aftereffect** of his 1998 conviction, the felon was unable to
>   find a job upon his release from prison in 2017 for two years."

As for your example, these ones don't necessarily have negative connotations; they are somewhat neutral:

"Everybody is still hyped up in its **wake**."

"Everybody is still hyped up **as a consequence of the wedding**."

"Everybody is still hyped up in its **backwash**."

"Afterglow" could work herein as well.  It has only a positive connotation:

"Everybody is still hyped up in its **afterglow**."

Answer (score -2):

This isn't an exact fit, but the word works for the given sentence.

> Everybody is still hyped up in its **afterglow**.

***Afterglow*** -- [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/afterglow)

> *noun* 2. a pleasant effect or feeling that lingers after something is done, experienced, or achieved.
>   *Basking in the afterglow of success.*

Comment: Though watch there's also a more [specific meaning associated with afterglow](http://www.encyclopedia.com/social-sciences/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/afterglow).

Answer (score -2):

> - after-party
> - afterwards
> - the festivities that followed
> - both parties were really one big party
> - the emotion carried forward

Answer (score -2):

You could use Post, Momentarily, Suddenly, Further on, On wards, After an hour, Afterglow, Corollary, Out come, End result, Follow up etc. This all mean, after an event or stage throughout the current era or you are in, that resumes/ continues throughout all History/ Antiquity.

Comment: I don't see how any of your eleven different answers fits the requirement in the question.